# How to improve Clustered Index scan to Clustered Index seek?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have two tables

```
[dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Role] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](1) NULL)

[dbo].[Roles](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Role] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](25) NULL)
```

with primary clustered keys by id.
Also I have stored procedure

```
SELECT
   [EmployeeID]
  ,[Title]
  ,employee.[Role]
  ,roles.Role AS RoleName
FROM [dbo].Employee AS employee
INNER JOIN [dbo].Roles AS roles ON roles.id = employee.Role
WHERE [Status] <> 'D'
```

The Execution plan shows me a 'Clustered Index Scan' that I want to avoid. Is there any way I can convert it to a 'Clustered Index Seek'?
[Execution Plan screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5ECp.png)

<[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8716c7f931170dfa71abd58f5bb005ee)>

Comment: Not with that query, no. The `CLUSTERED INDEX` is on `id` (and I assume `EmployeeID`), but you are filtering on the value of `Status`. If you had a covering index on `status` the RDBMS could use that to seek, though it may well chose not to, considering you are using a `<>`.

Comment: Step 1) Add a role foreign key.

Comment: You could try a filtered index `Employee (Role, EmployeeID) INCLUDE (Status, Title) WHERE (Status <> 'D')`. As mentioned, the join is unnecessary here, and would have been elided if you had a foreign key

Comment: Learn GOOD habits. Don't use brackets inconsistently. I suggest you don't use them at all unless absolutely necessary as they make your code difficult to read. In general SELECT queries should have an ORDER BY clause. DO use statement terminators. Tables that have all nullable columns except for an identity primary key column are logically flawed. And what exactly is variable about a 1 character column? THINK about your datatypes.

Comment: @SMor "In general `SELECT` queries should have an `ORDER BY` clause" where did you get that from? Yes, if the client app expects the rows in a particular order they should specify, but applications should be written to be *agnostic* to order and should not care, this reduces unnecessary sorting on the server. Agree with the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the `CLUSTERED INDEX` on `dbo.Employees` isn't going to help you here. The reason for this is because you are filtering on the column `status`, which is simply *included* in the `CLUSTERED INDEX`, but isn't ordered on it. As a result, the RDBMS has no option but to scan the entire table to filter out the rows where `Status` has a value of `D`.

You could add an `INDEX` on the column `Status` and `INCLUDE` the other columns, which *may* result in an index seek (not a clustered index seek), however, due to you using `<> D` then the RDBMS may feel still chose to perform a scan; whether it does depends on your data's distribution:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX_EmployeeStatus ON dbo.Employee (Status) INCLUDE (Title, Role);
```

Also add a `FOREIGN KEY` to your table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Employee ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeRole FOREIGN KEY (Role) REFERENCES dbo.Roles (id);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d58b058988f4c51d7d83d07117698c3)

Answer (score -4):

Provided you had an index on your Status column then that code should result in two index seeks. One for < 'D' and one for > 'D'. You just need an index on Status.

You can convert it to one seek using a temp table to flip your "Not" into an "is", which is always a good idea in query tuning:

```
CREATE TABLE #StatusMatch (StatusCode varchar(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
 INSERT INTO #StatusMatch WITH(TABLOCKX)
      SELECT Status 
        FROM dbo.Employee WITH(NOLOCK)
       WHERE Status <> 'D'
    GROUP BY Status
    ORDER BY Status;

      SELECT a.EmployeeID, a.Title, a.Role, b.Description AS RoleName
        FROM dbo.Employee a WITH(NOLOCK)
  INNER JOIN dbo.Roles b WITH(NOLOCK) ON a.Role = b.id
  INNER JOIN #StatusMatch c ON a.Status = c.StatusCode
```

Comment: `<> 'D'` can be done with an index seek operator. SQL Server can and does convert `<>` predicates to two range seeks (on `< 'D'` and  `> 'D'`). There is no suitable index in the OP's case that would allow this though

Comment: Why are you spamming `NOLOCK` here? If you *are* encouraging it's use (which you appear to be) at least **warn** the OP of all the problems or considerations they need to be aware of too: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Though `NOLOCK` isn't the magic "Go Faster" button you likely think it is. Also performing an `INSERT INTO` with a `NOLOCK` is generally a *terrible* idea. Also why use `TABLOCKX` on a temporary table where the *only* scope that is going to have access to it is the scope that created it?

Comment: Martin, I'm not sure that works on strings. It may well work on numerics. Larnu, you are mistaken, NOLOCK in this case improves performance. If OP is asking for query tuning advice, I think he wants to improve performance.

Comment: @OwlFace - I am sure. And you can easily test. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f66243c16cb2fef49681fb9ddbb8729

Comment: *"Larnu, you are mistaken, NOLOCK in this case improves performance"* No, no I am not.

Comment: Yes you are. A blog post saying not to use NOLOCK is not proof.

Comment: Separate note, please don't assume the gender of the users here, @OwlFace . You agreed to use gender neutral language when you signed up, per the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: I can give you a few more articles if you want, that discuss it's problems more if you like, @OwlFace . [1](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/01/but-surely-nolock-is-okay-if-no-ones-changing-data-right/), [2](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/11/nolock-is-bad-and-you-probably-shouldnt-use-it/), [3](http://www.sqlnuggets.com/nolock-may-not-be-doing-what-you-think/). The point is that it **doesn't** improve performance; it takes "short cuts" and ignores "safety" features that ensure the reliability your data. The query *might* be quicker, but it can be very wrong; which is far worse.

Comment: I know exactly how NOLOCK works, thanks. And in the vast majority of use cases, and in OPs query, it does increase performance. Depending on the size of the tables and number of joins, queries can be 10-20 times faster with NOLOCK enabled than without. The "Safety" features you mention were last relevant 20 years ago when storage controllers were much less reliable.

Comment: Oh and those are all blog posts, not articles. Brent Ozar is a well-known SQL contrarian with weird opinions on NOLOCK.

Comment: Apparently you *don't* know how `NOLOCK` works, if you did you would be recommending `SNAPSHOT` or `TABLOCK` depending whether you expect concurrent writees, both of these are far superior to `NOLOCK` in terms of consistency and give nearly the same performance boost. `NOLOCK` can cause: rows and even whole pages to be missed or double-read, rows that fail unique, primary, foreign or even check constraints, doubled-up joins which were supposed to be unique, torn LOB data, and can *still* cause blocking against DDL (which could easily happen on index rebuilds or synchronous stats updates)

Comment: 2 of those links above are not from Brent Ozar. Further articles: [by an actual MS employee](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/281562/220697) discouraging it, [by Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level) a mod on [dba.se], and [another by A Betrand showing completely corrupt LOB data](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6072/sql-server-nolock-anomalies-issues-and-inconsistencies/)

Comment: And regards your actual solution, you haven't gained any performance by using a temp table: you still need to query `WHERE Status <> 'D'` so indexing is still necessary, and now have the overhead of inserting into a temp table

Comment: Not sure who you think I'm impersonating, but I can assure you that I am not any of the above posters.  I made the point somewhat forcefully because `NOLOCK` has been dumped into [so] as a panacea so many times in the past, it's getting tiresome. I'm sorry you feel I'm getting angry, that wasn't the intention. I'm not mad, I just agree with all that has been said and would like to back them up, and I suggest you take on board articles/blogs/whatever that have been written by many well-respected people in the industry. You are welcome to your own opinion, just don't expect others to agree.